# replace pyqtplot by another pyqtplot in a qllayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am building a plot layout that is dynamically filled according to user selection based on 2 different parameters.

The first parameter is the variable that is desired to plot. This parameter will add plots to my plot layout.

The second parameter is the property that I wish to draw in all parameters plot.

In my code I am checking if selected parameter is plotted (or not) and adding a new plot if necessary.

After that I check if the property is plotted in those graphics.

If these properties are not plotted, I am trying to replace the original plot by a new one for each variable graphic with all selected parameter.

I am trying this approach because when I add a new property in my variables plots I am plotting it again and as consequence of that, I it appears multiple legends for the same property.

How can I replace the selected plot by another plot on the same layout position with new parameters?

```
for i in range(1,len(variables)): 
    if variables[i] not in plotted_variables:
        graph = pg.PlotWidget(scroll_Area)
        graph.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 300))
        graph.setTitle(variables[i])

        plotted_variables.append(variables[i])
        vertical_layout.addWidget(graph)
        graphics.append(graph)

        for j in range(1,len(properties)):
            X_dados = np.array([0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
            Y_dados = np.array([0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])*j
            graphics[i].plot(X_dados,Y_dados, name=properties[j])
            graphics[i].addLegend()



    else:
        if properties != plotted_prperties:
            new_graph = pg.PlotWidget()
            new_graph.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 300))
            new_graph.setTitle(variables[i])

            # self.plotted_variables[i] = variables[i]
            item =vertical_layout.takeAt(i)
            widget = item.widget()
            vertical_layout.replaceWidget(widget,new_graph)

            # self.graphics.append(new_graph)

            for j in range(1,len(properties)):
                X_dados = np.array([0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
                Y_dados = np.array([0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])*j
                graphics[i].plot(X_dados,Y_dados, name=properties[j])
                graphics[i].addLegend()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.

This may not be the best one (I noticed it is a little slow when we access big data banks and redraw more than 3 plots at once), but is working for me. If anyone has a better way to solve this issue, I'd like to see it too.

To my solution, I cleared all plotted data and created it again given the selected variables and properties. This approach solved the issue with labels and plotting area.

```
colors = ['', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', "y", 'k', 'w']
for i in range(len(graphics)-1,0,-1):
    vertical_layout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)
    graphics.pop(i)

for i in range(len(plotted_variables)-1,0,-1):
    plotted_variables.pop(i)

for i in range(len(plotted_properties)-1,0,-1):
    plotted_properties.pop(i)

# plotar gráficos
for i in range(1,len(variables)): 
    graph = pg.PlotWidget(scroll_Area)
    graph.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 300))
    graph.setTitle(variables[i])

    plotted_variables.append(variables[i])
    vertical_layout.addWidget(graph)
    graphics.append(graph)

    graphics[i].addLegend()
    for j in range(1,len(properties)):
        X_dados = np.array([0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
        Y_dados = np.array([0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])*j
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=colors[j])

        graphics[i].plot(X_dados,Y_dados, name=properties[j],pen=pen)
```